# SVProgressHUD is not working when open an app through click notification in iOS

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, xcode8, ios9, svprogresshud

I have already implemented `SVProgressHUD` to other pages into app. In this app notification feature is exist. when I received notification and then clicked it open an home page then navigate specific page. In this situation I want when I click notification that time I want to show `SVProgressHUD` until to navigate specific page. I have already implemented `SVProgressHUD` functionality under '`registerForPushNotification`' method but it's not working. It's working after navigate to specific page. So I don't understand what can I do. Please any one help me out. Is it possible?

Comment: Please any one suggest me, it is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,
add this:

```
//redirect to notification list if its from push notification click
NSMutableDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (notification)
{
    //this notification dictionary is same as your JSON payload whatever you gets from Push notification you can consider it as a userInfo dic in last parameter of method -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    NSLog(@"%@",notification);
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please Wait"];
}
```

Hope this will help ;)